# A Trace32 script simulator?

Tags: arm, trace32, lauterbach

I'm new to T32 script, and would like to test few scripts from the example of the user guide.
However, I don't have a target to hook up with, so I'm wondering if there are something like a simulator which I can try my scripts without connecting to a real device.
Just want to practice the language first.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TRACE32 can run as instruction set simulator by setting the operation mode in the configuration file that you have to provide on start-up. A minimal configuration file for starting the simulator looks like this:

```
PBI=SIM

PRINTER=WINDOWS

SCREEN=  
HEADER=TRACE32 ARM SIMULATOR
```

Using `PBI=SIM` makes sure that TRACE32 operates as instruction set simulator. You can specify configuration files on the command line with `<t32_executable> -c <config_file>`